# Can individual locators in LocatorPane be temporarily disabled?

Tags: manipulate, front-end, programming, interactive

This follows up on [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8878/restrict-sensitivity-of-locators-in-locatorpane) about the sensitivity of Locators in a a LocatorPane.

I would like to be able to enable/disable individual locators in a LocatorPane.
In the simplified version of the applet, pictured below, I would like to be able to disable the locators that set the slope of the red line, while allowing the locators that set the slope of the blue line to remain enabled.

[image: locators]

Using individual `Locator`s, rather than a `LocatorPane`, is not an option.  (There are some subtle issues that arise with individual locators.  Essentially, multiple `Locator`s can behave in a "flaky" fashion in complex applets, in ways that `LocatorPane` does not.)

Code below:

```
Manipulate[m = 15;
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
  Dynamic[ Module[{x = pts[[1, 1]], y = pts[[2, 2]], x2 = pts[[3, 1]], y2 = pts[[4, 2]]},
  Graphics[{
  {Blue, Line[{-m*{x2, y2}, m*{x2, y2}}]},
  Line[{{x2, 0}, {x2, y2}}], Line[{{x2, y2}, {0, y2}}],
  {Red, Line[{-m*{x, y}, m*{x, y}}]},
  Line[{{x, 0}, {x, y}}], Line[{{x, y}, {0, y}}]},
  PlotRange -> m, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> {300, 300}]]],
  {{{-m, 0}, {m, 0}, {1, 0}}, 
   {{0, -m}, {0, m}, {0, 1}}, 
   {{-m, 0}, {m, 0}, {1, 0}}, 
   {{0, -m}, {0, m}, {0, 1}}},
 Appearance -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}], 
 {{pts, {{6, 0}, {0, 9}, {3, 0}, {0, 7}}}, ControlType -> None}]
```

The **visibility** of the locators can be individually controlled by toggling the respective locator's `Appearance` between `None` and `Automatic`.  But even when the locator is invisible (i.e. `Appearance -> None`) it continues enabled.  For example, the red sliders will continue to set the slope of the red line.

A possible solution would be to obtain the `Appearance` setting of the red sliders and make the assignment of `x` and `y` contingent on the Appearance setting.

Comment: Could you describe briefly or link to a description of this unwanted "flaky" behavior of individual locators?

Comment: Ever time I tried to use individual locators (with out a LocatorPane I would run into a situation in which they would cease to be responsive after moving once.  I take this to mean that some routines needed to be wrapped in Dynamic, but I could never figure out a solution, no matter how much I tried.  So the flakiness may have been inherent to the Locators or a reflection of my inability to fully understand the use of Dynamic wrappers.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, if you have code that exhibits this problem I think you should add it to your question or add a new question for it.

Comment: The problem rears its head in the context of a couple pages of code. Generally I avoid inflicting large amounts of code on others.

Comment: "Generally I avoid inflicting large amounts of code on others." -- Something I think we all appreciate.  Nevertheless it might make in interesting question, and you certainly haven't made a pest of yourself with wall-of-code questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to change the `Dynamic` so that it updates only the points you want to be editable. Here is a very simple demonstration:

```
 pts = {{6, 0}, {0, 9}, {3, 0}, {0, 7}};
 updatable = Range@Length@pts;
 Button["Fixate point 3", (updatable = {1, 2, 4})]
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, (pts[[updatable]] = #[[updatable]]) &], 
 Dynamic@Graphics[Point /@ pts, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]]
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'll need some time before I can fully examine it, but it looks promising.

Comment: +1 It works like a charm. Very clever suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I like @jVincent's approach.

Here is a different approach  `Overlay`ing  `LocatorPanes` inside `Manipulate` :

```
locPane[Dynamic[pts_], shape_, color_] := 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
 Dynamic@Module[{x = pts[[1, 1]], y = pts[[2, 2]]}, 
 Graphics[{{color, Line[{-m*{x, y}, m*{x, y}}]}, 
  Line[{{x, 0}, {x, y}}], Line[{{x, y}, {0, y}}]}, PlotRange -> m,
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> {300, 300}]],
 {{{-m, 0}, {m, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, -m}, {0, m}, {0, 1}}},
 Appearance -> {shape, shape}];
(* locator apperance graphics *)
redCircle = Graphics[{Red, Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i], {i, 2}]}, ImageSize -> 10];
blueCircle = Graphics[{Blue, Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i], {i, 2}]}, ImageSize -> 10];
grayDisk =  Graphics[{Lighter@Lighter@Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, 2], 
 Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, 3]},  ImageSize -> 10];
```

**Method 1: `Overlay` two instances of `locPane` inside a `Manipulate`**

```
Manipulate[m = 15; 
 Overlay[{
  locPane[Dynamic[pts], Dynamic@If[layer == 1, redCircle, grayDisk], Red], 
  locPane[Dynamic[pts2], Dynamic@If[layer == 2, blueCircle, grayDisk], Blue]},
  All, Dynamic[layer]], 
{{pts, {{6, 0}, {0, 9}}}, ControlType -> None}, 
{{pts2, {{7, 0}, {0, 7}}}, ControlType -> None}, 
{{layer, 1, "layer"}, {1, 2}}]
```

to get

[image]

**Method 2: `Overlay` two instances of `locPane` inside an `EventHandler` and `Manipulate`:**

Right-mouse-click toggles between two locator panes:

```
DynamicModule[{layer = 1}, EventHandler[Manipulate[m = 15;
 Overlay[
{locPane[Dynamic[pts], Dynamic@If[layer == 1, redCircle, grayDisk], Red], 
 locPane[Dynamic[pts2], Dynamic@If[layer == 2, blueCircle, grayDisk], Blue]},
 All, Dynamic[layer]],
{{pts, {{6, 0}, {0, 9}}}, ControlType -> None},
{{pts2, {{7, 0}, {0, 7}}}, ControlType -> None}],
{{"MouseClicked", 2} :> ((layer = layer /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}))}, 
PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your solution after EDIT, each locator stops and freezes after moving one unit.  (This is precisely the sort of trouble I run into when I attempt to use Locator instead of LocatorPane.) I suspect that some variable needs to be wrapped in Dynamic.

Comment: @DavidCarraher, I think the version you are using is not the last one - I added `Dynamic` before `Module` in both versions to fix that same issue.