# Enabling/disabling individual locators within a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, locator

This [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14092/why-arent-the-locators-independently-enabled-disabled) helped me out somewhat but it is missing a piece that I really need for something that I am working on that's more complex than what I've shown below. I want to disable a `Locator` when its corresponding tab is not selected, I've achieved this using the method in the link, however it is slow (not with this simple code), `ContinuousAction->False` doesn't affect it, and when I click anywhere within the plot range the `Locator` does not move there and I haven't been able to change this.

```
clip[pt : {x_, y_}, {xMin_, yMin_}, {xMax_, yMax_}] := {Clip[
   x, {xMin, xMax}], Clip[y, {yMin, yMax}]}

Manipulate[
 Switch[ctrl,
  1, Show[
   Graphics[{
     {Thick, Line[{{-3, 0}, {point1[[1]], point1[[2]]}}]},
     Locator[Dynamic[point1, (point1 = clip[#, {-3, -2}, {3, 2}]) &], 
      Enabled -> True]
     }, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}]
   ],
  2, Show[
   Graphics[{
     {Thick, Red, Line[{{3, 0}, {point2[[1]], point2[[2]]}}]},
     Locator[Dynamic[point2, (point2 = clip[#, {-3, -2}, {3, 2}]) &], 
      Enabled -> True]
     },
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}]
   ]
  ],
 {{ctrl, 1, ""}, {1 -> "black", 2 -> "red"}, SetterBar},
 {{point1, {0, 1}}, None},
 {{point2, {0, -1}}, None}]
```

I'm not sure if it's possible, or if there is a completely different way of going about enabling/disabling individual locators (that isn't super messy). I just want to do that and also be able to use options like `ContinuousAction->False` and be able to click anywhere within the plot range and have the locator "jump" there.

What I've provided above is more or less what I learned from the other post, below is a short example of what I originally had.

```
Manipulate[
 Switch[ctrl,
  1, Show[
   Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{-3, 0}, {point1[[1]], point1[[2]]}}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}]
   ],
  2, Show[
   Graphics[{Thick, Red, Line[{{3, 0}, {point2[[1]], point2[[2]]}}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}]
   ]
  ],
 {{ctrl, 1, ""}, {1 -> "black", 2 -> "red"}, SetterBar},
 {{point1, {0, 1}}, Locator},
 {{point2, {0, -1}}, Locator}]
```

Comment: For anyone coming across this answer in the future, other options using LocatorPane can be found at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9148/can-individual-locators-in-locatorpane-be-temporarily-disabled. These will behave slightly differently, allowing you to click on a point to move the nearest enabled locator to it, rather than having to click and drag the locator.

Answer (score 2):

Based on M.Goldbergs answer it appears that you want both lines displayed? The way you had constructed your code was to only display one line at a time, therefore the enabling/disabling was redundant. There are other redundancies (e.g.`Switch`, `Part`), which when removed, and after a few small changes, gives you:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{-3, 0}, point1}], 
   Locator[Dynamic[point1], Enabled -> ctrl], Red, 
   Line[{{3, 0}, point2}], 
   Locator[Dynamic[point2], Enabled -> ! ctrl]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}],
 {{ctrl, True, ""}, {True -> "black", False -> "red"}, SetterBar},
 {{point1, {0, 1}}, None},
 {{point2, {0, -1}}, None}]
```

Your function should be included within `Initialization` or alternatively use `SaveDefinitions->True`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just had `Switch` in there because the notebook I am having trouble with contains it and needs it. I like your way of writing it better, it's faster too. I need to be able to use `ContinuousAction->False` and have it affect the locators too (if that's even possible) or have the locators "snap" to a point that I randomly click on within the plot range.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your `Switch` expression so it only controls the enabling and disabling of the locators. Further, you don't need to use `Show`. With such changes you get

```
With[{xRange = {-3, 3}, yRange = {-2, 2}},
 Manipulate[
   Switch[ctrl,
     1, redEnable = False; blackEnable = True,
     2, redEnable = True; blackEnable = False];
   Graphics[{
     Thick, Black, Line[{{-3, 0}, pt1}],
     Thick, Red, Line[{{3, 0}, pt2}],
     Locator[Dynamic[pt1, (pt1 = clip[#]) &], Enabled :> blackEnable],
     Locator[Dynamic[pt2, (pt2 = clip[#]) &], Enabled :> redEnable]},
     PlotRange -> {xRange, yRange}], 
   {{ctrl, 1, ""}, {1 -> "black", 2 -> "red"}, SetterBar},
   {{blackEnable, False}, None},
   {{redEnable, False}, None},
   {{pt1, {0, 1}}, None},
   {{pt2, {0, -1}}, None},
   Initialization :> (clip = {Clip[#[[1]], xRange], Clip[#[[2]], yRange]} &)]]
```

[image: black-selected]

[image: red-selected]