# How do I constrain the region where I can drag a Locator?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, gui-construction

How do I constrain the region where I can drag a `Locator` to conform to rules, including rules that apply to computations resulting from the value of the `Locator`?

I understand how I can impose some very general constraints using `LocatorRegion`'s `Automatic` and `Full` settings, but these don't (appear to) allow me to:

1. Limit a single coordinate the `Locator` can assume, while allowing the other coordinates to cover the entire range of a plot.
2. Limit the coordinates `Locators` can assume based on a constraint placed on a function they generate.

For example, in the following, code, how do (1) I constrain `c5` to the right hand edge of the figure (i.e to have an x value of 1) and (2) constrain all other `Locators` so that the resulting function never goes above the line y=x?

```
Manipulate[Show[
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}],
  ParametricPlot[f[{{0, 0}, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}][x], {x, 0, 1}]],
 {{c1, {.2, .2}}, Locator},
 {{c2, {.4, .4}}, Locator},
 {{c3, {.6, .6}}, Locator},
 {{c4, {.8, .8}}, Locator},
 {{c5, {1, 1}}, Locator},
 {{f, BezierFunction, "Form"}, {BezierFunction, BSplineFunction}}]
```

That is, I want to prevent this,

[image]

by ensuring (1) that `c5` stays at x=1, while being free to assume a range of y values; and this

[image]

by (2) preventing any of the `Locators` from being moved to locations that would result in the generated plot from passing above the y=x line -- though a `Locator` may still be allowed above that line if this condition is not violated:

[image]

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8882/5) for a simple example of constraining locators. Yours is a little more involved, because you're not constraining the locators directly, but indirectly in that they can move where ever as long as the curve doesn't cross $y=x$

Comment: @rm-rf: I'm sure how to apply that here. If I just replace `Locator` with `Locator[Dynamic[...]]`, the locator still behaves as before (though it becomes initially invisible).

Comment: Seen [this question/answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6031/125)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to define a "clipping" function that applies the constraints to the points:

```
clip[pts_] :=
  ReplacePart[pts /. {x_, y_} /; y > x :> {x, x}, {-1, 1} -> 1]
```

We can then invoke that function whenever the set of points is changed.  To use this strategy, it is convenient to use a single locator control for all points:

```
Manipulate[
  pts = clip[pts]
; Show[
    Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
  , ParametricPlot[f[Prepend[pts, {0, 0}]][x], {x, 0, 1}]
  ]
, {{pts, {{.2, .2}, {.4, .4}, {.6, .6}, {.8, .8}, {1, 1}}}, Locator}
, {{f, BezierFunction, "Form"}, {BezierFunction, BSplineFunction}}
]
```

*Edit*

My initial response only applied constraints to the input parameters.  The full requirement is to also apply constraints derived from the computed output.  The revised version below addresses that requirement.  The principle is the same, but now the computed output is checked to see if it is valid using the new function `validQ`.  If the output is not valid, then the inputs are reset to the previous values.

```
clip[pts_] :=
  ReplacePart[pts, {-1, 1} -> 1]

validQ[f_, pts_] :=
  Apply[And, #[[1]] >= #[[2]]& /@ Table[f[Prepend[pts, {0, 0}]][x], {x, 0, 1, 0.01}]]

Manipulate[
  pts2 = clip[pts2]
; If[validQ[f, pts2], pts1 = pts2, pts2 = pts1]
; Show[
    Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
  , ParametricPlot[f[Prepend[pts1, {0, 0}]][x], {x, 0, 1}]
  ]
, {{pts1, {{.2, .2}, {.4, .4}, {.6, .6}, {.8, .8}, {1, 1}}}, None}
, {{pts2, pts1}, Locator}
, {{f, BezierFunction, "Form"}, {BezierFunction, BSplineFunction}}
]
```

Note that `validQ` uses a crude numerical method to check whether the resulting curve lies under the `y = x` line -- a more accurate method might be needed for the real application.

**For Your Consideration: An Alternate Feedback Mechanism**

Personally, I do not like user interface components that place complex constraints upon my gestures.  In this case, I do not find the `x` constraint on the last locator to be objectionable.  However, I find it awkward to move the other locators since the constraints are complex functions of the output.  I try to move the locator in a direction that I think will be helpful, but it just will not move.  I have to guess which *other* locator to move out of the way first, and then go back and move the first locator.

I would propose a different paradigm.  Let the user move the locators however they want, but give them clear feedback when their inputs are not valid.  For example:

```
Manipulate[
  pts = ReplacePart[pts, {-1, 1} -> 1]
; valid = True
; Column[
    { Show[
        Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
      , ParametricPlot[
          f[Prepend[pts, {0, 0}]][x], {x, 0, 1}
        , ColorFunction -> (If[#1 >= #2, Black, valid = False; Red]&)
        , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
        ]
      ]
    , If[valid, "Valid", Style["Invalid", Red]]
    }
  ]
, {{pts, {{.2, .2}, {.4, .4}, {.6, .6}, {.8, .8}, {1, 1}}}, Locator}
, {{f, BezierFunction, "Form"}, {BezierFunction, BSplineFunction}}
, {valid, None}
]
```

[image: valid state screenshot]

[image: invalid state screenshot]

At the cost of some added code complexity, smoother animation of the last locator can be obtained by explicit use of a `LocatorPane`:

```
Manipulate[
  Column[
    { LocatorPane[
        Dynamic[pts, (pts = ReplacePart[#, {-1, 1} -> 1]) &]
      , Dynamic@Show[
          Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
        , valid = True
        ; ParametricPlot[
            f[Prepend[pts, {0, 0}]][x], {x, 0, 1}
          , ColorFunction -> (If[#1 >= #2, Black, valid = False; Red]&)
          , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
          ]
        ]
      ]
    , Dynamic@If[valid, "Valid", Style["Invalid", Red]]
    }
  ]
, {{pts, {{.2, .2}, {.4, .4}, {.6, .6}, {.8, .8}, {1, 1}}}, None}
, {{f, BezierFunction, "Form"}, {BezierFunction, BSplineFunction}}
, {valid, None}
, TrackedSymbols :> {f}
]
```

Comment: My understanding of the question is slightly different... I think they want the locators to be able to move above the line too, but constrained such that the curve never crosses y==x. It's a bit tricky, because an individual locator is not absolutely constrained; rather, all of them together decide (via the curve) whether a particular locator can be moved to some position or not (see the third figure in the OP)

Comment: @rm-rf Agreed.  I lost that point somewhere along the way while implementing my solution.  I will rethink.

Comment: Two parts. The second is as @rm-rf describes it, the first is simply to constrain one of the Locators to always have an x value of 1.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Is the last locator not constrained for you?  It is for me using V7 or V8.

Comment: What's "V7 or V8"?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I mean that my exhibited code is constraining the position of the last locator whether I am using Mathematica version 7 or version 8.

Comment: @rm-rf After wrestling with some typical `Manipulate` race conditions, I have posted an updated version that checks the validity of the generated curve.

Comment: Hmm... disregard my previous comment. It does work, but not in all cases. I guess that's what you meant by `validQ` using a crude method. Nevertheless, +1 :)

Comment: very nice indeed, +1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the UI. In general that's a far superior solution to what I was asking for (though I have additional constraints which make it inappropriate). The really urgent UI big though is finding a way to prevent the "ghosting" and "jumping around" of the last control point caused by the locking to the right axis.

Comment: Ah, I see: hide the control points, and draw some `Points` instead — no flashing.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes.  Or, we could take control of the locators away from `Manipulate` by introducing an explicit `LocatorPane` -- see my edit.

Comment: Ugh: [now I can't get the context menu](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13867/37) I use to print and export.