# How can I restore context menu functionality to a Manipulate that contains Locators?

Tags: graphics, export, manipulate, printing

Before adding a `Locator` to a `Manipulate`, I can easily print or export the result using a context menu:

[image]

But after adding a `Locator`, I can't even get a context menu to appear. How do I enable graphics generated with `Locators` so that the context menu functionality is restored?

```
    Manipulate[
     Show[ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, c1, {1, 1}}][x], {x, 0, 1}]],
    {{c1,{.2, .2}}, Locator}]
```

Comment: It's not about `Manipulate`, the same behaviour can be seen in a simple `Graphics` object, as the `Locator` intercepts all mouse events: try this: `{Graphics[{Circle[]}], Graphics[{Circle[], Locator[{0, 0}]}]}`. I'm thinking of an easier workaround than creating an `EventHandler` in a `DynamicModule`...

Comment: It probably uses `Deployed` to make it unselectable so that there is no ambiguity as to whether a click meant "move the locator" or "select the figure". Have you tried clicking the `+` and selecting "Paste Snapshot"?

Comment: @rm-rf:  Can I just set `Deployed` to `False` somewhere when I disable the Locator? If so, it's not clear where.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution but it exports.

```
nb = CreateDocument[{Manipulate[
     Show[ParametricPlot[
       BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, c1, {1, 1}}][x], {x, 0, 
        1}]], {{c1, {.2, .2}}, Locator}]}];
NotebookPrint[nb, "temp.pdf"]
```

Comment: As I understand the question it's not about the export functionality itself rather it is about getting the context menu that contains it.

Comment: This is helpful. Better along these lines would be to `img=Show...` and then add `Row[{Button["Print", NotebookPrint[img]]}]`.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries the title states print or export ...

Comment: Yeah, but the body text (the actual question) says: "How do I enable graphics generated with Locators so that the context menu functionality is restored?"

Comment: Body or title :))))

Comment: Both. See edit. Sorry for the confusion.