# Moving From Dynamic Module to Manipulate

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

In trying to implement Vitaly's [suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8878/restrict-sensitivity-of-locators-in-locatorpane/8884#8884) about how to take control of `Locator` events,
I have been able to make headway using `DynamicModule`. However, the ultimate destination is a demonstration, so I'd like to make the code work in `Manipulate`.

**The Code**

The following pared-down version works fine.  It places 5 locators in a coordinate space with *x* and *y* axes displayed.

```
DynamicModule[{p1 = {0, 2}, p2 = {2, 0}, p3 = {4, -3}, p4 = {-3, 3}, p5 = {1, 1}},
EventHandler[
dQ[p_, q_] := EuclideanDistance[p, MousePosition["Graphics"]] < 
EuclideanDistance[q, MousePosition["Graphics"]];
Dynamic[
 Style[Graphics[{
  {Red, Disk[{0, Round@p1[[2]]}, .2]},
  {Blue, Disk[Round@p2, .2]},
  {Green, Disk[p3, .2]},
  {Brown, Disk[p4, .2]},
  GraphicsGroup[{Black, Line[{.1 {0, 1.5} + p5, .1 {0, 3} + p5}], 
    Line[{.1 {0, -1.5} + p5, .1 {0, -3} + p5}], 
    Line[{.1 {-1.5, 0} + p5, .1 {-3, 0} + p5}], 
    Line[{.1 {1.5, 0} + p5, .1 {3, 0} + p5}], 
    Circle[{0, 0} + p5, .2], Gray, Disk[p5, .1]}]},
 PlotRange -> 5, Axes -> True],Selectable -> False]],
 {"MouseDragged" :>
  (Which[
  dQ[p1, p2] && dQ[p1, p3] && dQ[p1, p4] && dQ[p1, p5], 
  p1 = MousePosition["Graphics"],
  dQ[p2, p1] && dQ[p2, p3] && dQ[p2, p4] && dQ[p2, p5], 
  p2 = MousePosition["Graphics"],
  dQ[p3, p1] && dQ[p3, p2] && dQ[p3, p4] && dQ[p3, p5], 
  p3 = MousePosition["Graphics"],
  dQ[p4, p1] && dQ[p4, p2] && dQ[p4, p3] && dQ[p4, p5], 
  p4 = MousePosition["Graphics"],
  dQ[p5, p1] && dQ[p5, p2] && dQ[p5, p3] && dQ[p5, p4], 
  p5 = MousePosition["Graphics"]])}]]
```

**Moving to Manipulate**

The issue is really quite simple. How can I successfully wrap this code in `Manipulate`?
I've tried this:

```
 Manipulate[ 
   <above code>,
   {x,1,12,Slider} ]
```

[The slider serves no purpose at the moment.]

**What happens**

The manipulate screen appears as expected. However, evaluation goes into a loop. The cell right bracket blinks endlessly.

What causes this loop?  Why doesn't it occur when I use `DynamicModule` without `Manipulate`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't have initialization code inside of the `Manipulate`.  You're defining the function `dQ` inside the `Manipulate`, and by moving that definition to the `Initialization` option of `Manipulate`, you can make this behave much better.

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{p1 = {0, 2}, p2 = {2, 0}, p3 = {4, -3}, p4 = {-3, 3}, 
   p5 = {1, 1}}, EventHandler[
   Dynamic[
    Style[Graphics[{{Red, Disk[{0, Round@p1[[2]]}, .2]}, {Blue, 
        Disk[Round@p2, .2]}, {Green, Disk[p3, .2]}, {Brown, 
        Disk[p4, .2]}, 
       GraphicsGroup[{Black, Line[{.1 {0, 1.5} + p5, .1 {0, 3} + p5}],
          Line[{.1 {0, -1.5} + p5, .1 {0, -3} + p5}], 
         Line[{.1 {-1.5, 0} + p5, .1 {-3, 0} + p5}], 
         Line[{.1 {1.5, 0} + p5, .1 {3, 0} + p5}], 
         Circle[{0, 0} + p5, .2], Gray, Disk[p5, .1]}]}, 
      PlotRange -> 5, Axes -> True], 
     Selectable -> 
      False]], {"MouseDragged" :> (Which[
       dQ[p1, p2] && dQ[p1, p3] && dQ[p1, p4] && dQ[p1, p5], 
       p1 = MousePosition["Graphics"], 
       dQ[p2, p1] && dQ[p2, p3] && dQ[p2, p4] && dQ[p2, p5], 
       p2 = MousePosition["Graphics"], 
       dQ[p3, p1] && dQ[p3, p2] && dQ[p3, p4] && dQ[p3, p5], 
       p3 = MousePosition["Graphics"], 
       dQ[p4, p1] && dQ[p4, p2] && dQ[p4, p3] && dQ[p4, p5], 
       p4 = MousePosition["Graphics"], 
       dQ[p5, p1] && dQ[p5, p2] && dQ[p5, p3] && dQ[p5, p4], 
       p5 = MousePosition["Graphics"]])}]], {x, 1, 12, Slider}, 
 Initialization :> (dQ[p_, q_] := 
    EuclideanDistance[p, MousePosition["Graphics"]] < 
     EuclideanDistance[q, MousePosition["Graphics"]])]
```

EDIT:

I should say something else about this answer.  I answered the question you asked, but the way I answered it exposes another potential problem.  `Manipulate` wraps its entire contents in a `Dynamic`.  If that outer `Dynamic` happens to re-trigger, it will recreate the `DynamicModule` and reinitialize all of your `DynamicModule` variables.  This would certainly happen when you close and reopen the notebook.  It could also happen if you add dependencies to the Manipulate variables outside of the inner `Dynamic`.  So, really, a better version of my answer would be to move the `DynamicModule` out of the `Manipulate` like this:

```
DynamicModule[{p1 = {0, 2}, p2 = {2, 0}, p3 = {4, -3}, p4 = {-3, 3}, 
  p5 = {1, 1}}, Manipulate[EventHandler[
   Dynamic[
    Style[Graphics[{{Red, Disk[{0, Round@p1[[2]]}, .2]}, {Blue, 
        Disk[Round@p2, .2]}, {Green, Disk[p3, .2]}, {Brown, 
        Disk[p4, .2]}, 
       GraphicsGroup[{Black, Line[{.1 {0, 1.5} + p5, .1 {0, 3} + p5}],
          Line[{.1 {0, -1.5} + p5, .1 {0, -3} + p5}], 
         Line[{.1 {-1.5, 0} + p5, .1 {-3, 0} + p5}], 
         Line[{.1 {1.5, 0} + p5, .1 {3, 0} + p5}], 
         Circle[{0, 0} + p5, .2], Gray, Disk[p5, .1]}]}, 
      PlotRange -> 5, Axes -> True], 
     Selectable -> 
      False]], {"MouseDragged" :> (Which[
       dQ[p1, p2] && dQ[p1, p3] && dQ[p1, p4] && dQ[p1, p5], 
       p1 = MousePosition["Graphics"], 
       dQ[p2, p1] && dQ[p2, p3] && dQ[p2, p4] && dQ[p2, p5], 
       p2 = MousePosition["Graphics"], 
       dQ[p3, p1] && dQ[p3, p2] && dQ[p3, p4] && dQ[p3, p5], 
       p3 = MousePosition["Graphics"], 
       dQ[p4, p1] && dQ[p4, p2] && dQ[p4, p3] && dQ[p4, p5], 
       p4 = MousePosition["Graphics"], 
       dQ[p5, p1] && dQ[p5, p2] && dQ[p5, p3] && dQ[p5, p4], 
       p5 = MousePosition["Graphics"]])}], {x, 1, 12, Slider}, 
  Initialization :> (dQ[p_, q_] := 
     EuclideanDistance[p, MousePosition["Graphics"]] < 
      EuclideanDistance[q, MousePosition["Graphics"]])]]
```

Comment: I continue to have an unending updating problem with this code. Perhaps I didn't understand.  You eliminated the DynamicModule?

Comment: @DavidCarraher Sorry, I had a typo/oversight in my original answer which made the resulting code not clear.  I've edited and just included the entire code, along with a slight clarifying statement about the nature of the edit.

Comment: Thanks, nice how the Manipulate is wrapped in a DynamicModule.

Answer (score 13):

One way to do this is to add `TrackedSymbols` option to `Manipulate` - so it will update only when "tracked" variables are changed.

```
Manipulate[ 
   <above code>,
   {x,1,12,Slider}, TrackedSymbols :> {x} ]
```

This is the way when you'd like to specify specific controls. Another way to do the same thing  for **all** variables that are listed in controls is

```
Manipulate[ 
   <above code>,
   {x,1,12,Slider}, TrackedSymbols :> True ]
```

Comment: So simple a solution to so aggravating a problem. Thanks.