# Can Table be used inside Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, list-manipulation

**EDIT: CHanged the code. Please try again t see if it works well on our PCs.**

I am creating a simple Manipulate[] notebook. However when I place Table[] in the code, like:

```
Manipulate[ 
 OK = True;


 ai = ConstantArray[0, MaxIter + 1]; 
 bi = ConstantArray[0, MaxIter + 1]; 
 ci = ConstantArray[0, MaxIter + 1];
 ai[[1]] = a0; bi[[1]] = b0; ci[[1]] = (ai[[1]] + bi[[1]])/2;
 Table[ (*This instruction causes problems*)
  a = ai[[j - 1]]; b = bi[[j - 1]]; c = ci[[j - 1]];
  If[(f /. x -> a) (f /. x -> c) <= 0, ai[[j]] = ai[[j - 1]]; 
   bi[[j]] = ci[[j - 1]];, 
   If[(f /. x -> b) (f /. x -> c) <= 0, ai[[j]] = ci[[j - 1]]; 
     bi[[j]] = bi[[j - 1]];, OK = False; break;];];
  ci[[j]] = (ai[[j]] + bi[[j]])/2;
  , {j, 2, i}];

 If[OK, Show[Plot[f, {x, a0, b0}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
   PlotLabel -> "Metoda bisekcji", ImageSize -> Large]]
 , 
 (*controls*)

 Dynamic@Column@{
    Control[{{f, x^2 - 1, "f(x)="}, {x^2 - 1, Cos[x] - x}}],
    Control[{{method, "Bisekcji", "Metoda:"}, {"Bisekcji", "Newtona", 
       "Iteracji prostej", "Siecznych"}}],
    Sequence @@ 
     If[method == "Bisekcji" || 
       method == 
        "Siecznych" , {Control[{{a0, 1/2, 
          "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(0\)]\)="}}], 
       Control[{{b0, 2, 
          "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(b\), \(0\)]\)="}}]}, {Control[{{x0, 2,
           "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)="}}]}],
    Control[{{i, 1, "Iteracja"}, 1, 5, 1}]
    },
 (*Initialization*)
 Initialization :> (
   MaxIter = 5;
   ) 
 ]
```

The cell containing the GUI keeps evaluating all the time and the displayed content keeps being refreshed and looks like shaking. Is it normal?

Comment: The behavior you describe is not replicated on my Mac with Mathematica 9.0.1  Why not try `ClearAll[x,j,i]` before running the code?

Comment: Then Mathematica gets suspended

Comment: Working as expected on Mathematica 9.0.1 on Win7.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the described problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @YvesKlett: Changed the code, now it should make such behaviour on other PC's

Comment: What did you post your first example for? Now you have completely different and horribly formatted code which does not at all look inviting.

Comment: what's `break`?

Comment: It looks as if you are never getting to the command `OK=False`, which means that you do the plot repeatedly. So look for something in the logic preceeding that. This explains why the non-command `break` doesn't matter, you are never reaching it either.

Comment: @bill good catch, I thought the `break` might be the problem, but it's just a red herring...

Comment: These answers are relevant to this question: [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19737/manipulate-flickering-and-consuming-lots-of-cpu/19740#19740), [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18978/moving-from-dynamic-module-to-manipulate/18979#18979)

Comment: once you get this working you might consider posting a question asking how to do this without using `Table`. I suspect more efficient methods would be posted as answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that some variables are set in the main body of the `Manipulate` every time the `Manipulate` is updated.  This triggers another update...ad infinitum.

Use `TrackedSymbols` to control when an update is triggered.

```
Manipulate[OK = True;
 ai = ConstantArray[0, MaxIter + 1];
 bi = ConstantArray[0, MaxIter + 1];
 ci = ConstantArray[0, MaxIter + 1];
 ai[[1]] = a0; bi[[1]] = b0; ci[[1]] = (ai[[1]] + bi[[1]])/2;
 Table[(*This instruction causes problems*)a = ai[[j - 1]]; 
  b = bi[[j - 1]]; c = ci[[j - 1]];
  If[(f /. x -> a) (f /. x -> c) <= 0, ai[[j]] = ai[[j - 1]];
   bi[[j]] = ci[[j - 1]];, 
   If[(f /. x -> b) (f /. x -> c) <= 0, ai[[j]] = ci[[j - 1]];
     bi[[j]] = bi[[j - 1]];, OK = False; break;];];
  ci[[j]] = (ai[[j]] + bi[[j]])/2;, {j, 2, i}];
 If[OK, Show[Plot[f, {x, a0, b0}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
   PlotLabel -> "Metoda bisekcji", ImageSize -> Large]],

 (*controls*)
 Dynamic@Column@{Control[{{f, x^2 - 1, "f(x)="}, {x^2 - 1, 
       Cos[x] - x}}], 
    Control[{{method, "Bisekcji", "Metoda:"}, {"Bisekcji", "Newtona", 
       "Iteracji prostej", "Siecznych"}}], 
    Sequence @@ 
     If[method == "Bisekcji" || 
       method == 
        "Siecznych", {Control[{{a0, 1/2, 
          "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(0\)]\)="}}], 
       Control[{{b0, 2, 
          "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(b\), \(0\)]\)="}}]}, {Control[{{x0, 2,
           "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)="}}]}], 
    Control[{{i, 1, "Iteracja"}, 1, 5, 1}]},

 TrackedSymbols :> {i, a0, b0, method, f},

 (*Initialization*)Initialization :> (MaxIter = 5;)]
```

The rest of it needs work, apparently, but `TrackedSymbols` solves the continual-updating problem.  One can also simply set `TrackedSymbols -> True` to track only the control variables.