# Fourier Series plot

Tags: plotting, dynamic, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to plot partial sum of Fourier series. I've finally managed to make it work but there are several things I don't understand

```
f = Piecewise[{{Mod[x, Pi], Mod[x, 2 Pi] < Pi}, {Mod[-x, Pi], Mod[x, 2 Pi] >= Pi}}]
g = FourierSeries[f, x, 2]
Plot[{g, f}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

My questions are :

1. Why does it stop working when I directly put the value of g in Plot (only f is plotted) ?

   ```
   f = Piecewise[{{Mod[x, Pi], Mod[x, 2 Pi] < Pi}, {Mod[-x, Pi],Mod[x, 2 Pi]>= Pi}}]
   Plot[{FourierSeries[f, x, 2], f}, {x, -10, 10}]
   ```
2. Why does it stop working when I define g like this (only f is plotted)?

   ```
   g[x_] := FourierSeries[f, x, 2]
   Plot[{g[x], f}, {x, -10, 10}]
   ```
3. I also tried to add a slider to set the number terms to add. It seems to work but it makes Mathematica freeze...

   ```
   f = Piecewise[{{Mod[x, Pi], Mod[x, 2 Pi] < Pi}, {Mod[-x, Pi],Mod[x, 2 Pi] >= Pi}}]
   Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 10, 1}]
   Dynamic[g = FourierSeries[f, x, n]]
   Dynamic[Plot[{g, f}, {x, -10, 10}]]
   ```

Thanks :) !

Comment: Re 1: Because `x` is set to a numeric value before the series is computed. Re 2: Ditto; use `g[x_?NumericQ] := FourierSeries[f, x, 2]`. Re 3: Totally different. You get into a `Dynamic` infinite loop because setting `g` causes another update. Try `Dynamic[g = FourierSeries[f, x, n], TrackedSymbols :> {n}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I can put my comment in an answer:

- Re 1: Because `x` is set to a numeric value before the series is computed.
- Re 2: Ditto; use `g[x_?NumericQ] := FourierSeries[f, x, 2]`.
- Re 3: Totally different. You get into a `Dynamic` infinite loop because setting `g` causes another update. Try `Dynamic[g = FourierSeries[f, x, n], TrackedSymbols :> {n}]`.

The first two questions are more or less a duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)

The third question comes up in so many forms, it's hard to find an exact duplicate.  The underlying issue in [Can Table be used inside Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33990/can-table-be-used-inside-manipulate/34005#34005) is the same, although it's a rather complicated example compared to this one.

Comment: Thanks ! I learned a lot from those two links !